# ERROR: problem running /home/circleci/project/ansible/inventory.yml --list ([Errno 8] Exec format error)

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, circleci

I deploy my project automatically using CircleCI. I tried to run ansible locally with no problems but I can't seem to run the same commands on circleci machine.

Code circleci config:

```
- add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "my:fin:ger:pri:nt"
- run:
          name: deploy application by ansible
          command: |
            cd ansible
            ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml -e 'record_host_keys=True' -u ec2-user playbook.yml
          environment:
            ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: False
```

Code of inventory.yml:

```
all:
  hosts:
    "My EC2-IP"
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: Are you using a dynamic inventory ? Because ansible is trying to execute your yaml inventory file and does not succeed. If yes, you need to find out what is the problem (e.g. missing binary declared in shebang...). If no, you need to find out why it thinks it's dynamic.

Comment: You have failed to specify what version of ansible you are using, and also what the output is of `cd ansible && ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml --list` (meaning, what does ansible think based on whatever is in that directory)